# ORA-01722: invalid number in dbms_output.put_line

Tags: oracle, plsql

this a part of package for room reservations in hotel(for simplify the error I deleted date parameters):

```
create or replace package room_reservation
is
PROCEDURE are_free_rooms (
        room_capacity   IN NUMBER,
        room_category   IN VARCHAR2);
end;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY room_reservation IS

    PROCEDURE are_free_rooms (
        room_capacity   IN NUMBER,
        room_category   IN VARCHAR2
    ) IS

        v_room_id   NUMBER;
        CURSOR rooms IS SELECT
            r.room_id
                        FROM
            rooms r
            LEFT JOIN reservations res ON r.room_id = res.room_id
            JOIN room_category rc ON rc.category_id = r.room_category
                        WHERE
            r.capacity = room_capacity
            AND rc.name = room_category
               ;

    BEGIN
        FOR v_room_id IN rooms LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(v_room_id.room_id);
        END LOOP;
    END;

END;
```

All is compiling, but when I want to call procedure I got an error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
begin
ROOM_RESERVATION.ARE_FREE_ROOMS(4,'vip');
end;
Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.ROOM_RESERVATION", line 65
ORA-06512: at line 2
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

I trying to solve this problem and I dont know where I have problem with String, couse as I readed:

> An ORA-01722 error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a
>   character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted
>   into a number.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `room_category` is an **INTEGER** in `rooms` table and **VARCHAR2** in procedure parameter which causes implicit conflict.
When you run your query, in SQL context your column name has higher priority then binding parameter.

Please change your input variable name from `room_category`  to `p_room_category` in order to avoid conflicts

Comment: thanks I didnt think about that. Now it works. I have a lesson for the future :)